# Which cost function should be used for t-distributed noise?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, t-distribution

I'm new to Machine Learning. I've looked around and it seems that when we assume that a certain process has an underlying function plus some normally distributed noise, then a good choice for the cost function is the MSE.

So my question is: If we assume that our noise is t-distributed instead, which would be the best cost function to use?

I couldn't find this anywhere!

Comment: cost function choice is not driven by the noise distribution

Answer (score -1):

The t-distribution approaches the normal distribution asymptotically. So, if you are using a reasonably-sized dataset, the t-distribution will approximate the normal distribution, which means you can simply rely on the normal assumption.

With most ML applications to work well, your dataset will need more than a few hundred observations, and this would generally be considered "reasonably-sized."

Comment: This is not correct.  To see this, consider a t distribution with a shape parameter of 1, i.e., the Cauchy distribution.  The process has an underlying function plus some Cauchy-distributed noise.  As a result, the error variance is undefined for each observation even if you know the true model, and MSE is a terrible cost function.  Adding more data points with undefined variances (and undefined means, for that matter) won't help!

Comment: @jbowman you seem to know your stats! Do you know where I can learn more about this or can you answer?

Comment: @jbowman - if there is more than one df, which should be the case in this application, the Cauchy distribution does not apply... making it a one-off and muddying the waters on the subject. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution

Comment: Not so!  If you have, let us say, a t(3) distribution, having 10,000 data points with t(3) errors doesn't somehow transform those t(3) errors into Normal errors.  The point is that having lots of data points doesn't create Normally distributed errors, even though the parameter estimates themselves may become Normally distributed.  And if you have very heavy-tailed errors relative to the Normal, using loss functions such as MSE can render your estimates highly sensitive to outliers that are actually "valid" outliers, if you see what I mean.

Comment: In the cases similar to the case in the question, each data point (if it's i.i.d. and from a normal distribution) adds to the df... so, the distribution would be t(n-1). This is a standard assumption. Granted, if you are adding data *sets* together or you have reason to believe your data isn't normal and i.i.d, you are correct, otherwise the standard approach is the one to use.

Comment: I really think you are making the mistake of thinking about the distribution of the parameter estimates, for which your statement is correct, rather than the impact of the error distribution on an appropriate choice of cost function, which is what it seems to me the OP is asking about.  If your errors are, say, Laplace, and you want to maximize the likelihood, your cost function will be $\Sigma |e_i|$, for example, not MSE.  The fact that you have many observations doesn't change this, because the errors themselves remain Laplace.